# laravel model not workin

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

I am newbie with Laravel , I'm having some problems with the models.

cities have a table with the following columns: -id -Country_code -City and the model is :

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait; 
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

Class City extends Eloquent {

 protected $table = 'City';

 protected $fillable = array('Country_code', 'City');



 public function getRememberToken() {
   return 0;
 }

 public function setRememberToken($token) {
   return 0;
 }

 public function getRememberTokenName()
 {
  return 0;
 }
 }
```

also I have a countries table with the following columns :

-id -Country

and the model is :

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait; 
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

Class Pais extends Eloquent {

 protected $table = 'Country';

 protected $fillable = array('id', 'Country');




public function getRememberToken() {
   return 0;
}

public function setRememberToken($token) {
 return 0;
}

public function getRememberTokenName()
{
 return 0;
}
}
```

when I packed a dropbox, the country model works well ,

When I populate the dropbox cities , the following error occurs : ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

chrome on the console :

ailed to load resource: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE net :: http : // localhost / travellab / public / quote Failed to load resource: ERR_CACHE_MISS net :: http : // localhost / travellab / public / quote

can someone help ? What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to link foreign keys ?

Comment: didn't you ask this question yesterday too?

Comment: yes but I changed some text that was in Spanish

Comment: do you know what im doing wrong?

Comment: i do not use eloquent so sorry, no idea. i use fluent.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your snippet like this and check..

This what I have used in my model and works fine...

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Adminuser extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $table = 'users';

    // Define fields that cannot be set by mass assignment
    protected $guarded = [ 'id', 'DateCreated', 'DateModified' ];
```